# not able to activate windows xp in oracle virtualbox

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtualbox, windows-activation

I installed Oracle VirtualBox and used my Windows XP home edition to run in the VirtualBox.

Is it working, but I get all the time the reminder I have to register. This seems not to work as is tries to connect to the internet and is not able to do reach it. What can I do? Is there a way to get rid of this activation?

Comment: Does the machine have Internet connection up and working? Can you browse websites? Also, do you know that you need a separate license for virtualised OS (you can't use the same copy that you have on any other physical or virtual machine)?

Comment: You mean I have to buy a new windowx XP license? I did not know. Not good!

Comment: Why is this being voted to close as *off topic*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I activate WindowsXP now that support has ended?](https://superuser.com/questions/1502796/how-do-i-activate-windowsxp-now-that-support-has-ended)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Phone activation method?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307890

> How to activate Windows XP by phone :
>
> To contact a Microsoft customer
> service representative to activate Windows by phone, follow these
> steps:
>
> 1.Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Accessories,
> point to System Tools, and then click Activate Windows.
>
> Or, click the Windows Activation icon in the notification area.
>
> 2.Click Yes, I want to telephone a customer service representative to active Windows now.
>
> 3.Click Read the Windows Product Activation Privacy Statement, click Back, and then click Next.
>
> 4.Follow the steps in the Activate Windows by phone dialog box, and then click Next.
>
> Note The number appears now and differs based on the location that you
> select.
>
> 5.When activation is completed and you receive the following message, click OK. You have successfully activated your copy of Windows.