# How to properly execute this?

Tags: command-line

```
@echo off && cd /d "."
rem :: the windows reg key used to activate process in this bat/cmd read/write/delete ::  
set "_wpaKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WPAEvents"

reg query  "%_WPAKey%" | find /i "OOBETimer"                & rem/ output key value in screen
reg export "%_WPAKey%" ".\PAEvents_SAVE_Original.Reg"       & rem/ save original value in file
reg delete "%_WPAKey%" /v "OOBETimer" /f >nul               & rem/ remove the key/value
reg add    "%_wpaKey%" /v OOBETimer /t REG_BINARY /f        & rem/ recreate the key/value
timeout /t -1 2> nul                                        & rem/ time out to see the results
cd /d "C:\WINDOWS\system32\oobe"                            & rem/ goto to drive/folder C:\WINDOWS\system32\oobe\
start "" /realtime C:\WINDOWS\system32\oobe\msoobe.exe /a   & rem/ start the activate windows interface 
echo/:: sample key !! --^>  ISAY-REIN-STAT-EMO-NICA^!       & rem/ if need put some windows key to view/copy/paste   
pause >nul
```

Comment: Why is this script messing around in the registry instead of calling slmgr.vbs to install the key?

Comment: @user1686 Probably because slmgr.vbs didn't exist back in the WinXP days. OP is trying to activate WinXP using https://superuser.com/a/1502908/1482432

Answer (score 0):

You should save that to a textfile using your favourite text editor (e.g. Notepad). Then rename the file and change the extension to .bat. Then doubleclick on it and it will be executed.

If it asks something like "If you change the file name extension, the file might become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it", then click Yes.

It is a Batch file. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file

Comment: many tnx!! Though this still has not solve activation issues for windows xp pro sp3 ver.2003 ☹️

Comment: @Jojo You could try the other options mentioned here: https://superuser.com/questions/1502796/how-do-i-activate-windowsxp-now-that-support-has-ended/1502908#1502908