# Move the "find window" out of the way in Windows 11 Notepad

Tags: windows-11, notepad

The Windows 11 Notepad has been redesigned and features a new find/replace window. Let's say I have the following text:

[image: screenshot without find]

and I jump to the start of the text and search for all occurrences of "amet":

[image: find screenshot]

The position marker in the lower left-hand corner (highlighted by me) indicates that the word has been found in the first line, *but I can't see it, because the find window is in the way*.

Is there a way to move the find window so that I can see the results without having to close and re-open the find window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to solve this, as soon as the search window is shown it's possible to scroll up, so the search window does hide anything anymore:

Without search window:
[image]

With search window (you can see the scrollbar indicator changed):
[image]

Now it's possible to scroll up ("above" the first line):
[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: @Heinzi Your welcome, thanks for the upvote, if you don't mind my asking, I'm still waiting patiently on my 100th vote on this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1502796/how-do-i-activate-windowsxp-now-that-support-has-ended), if you find it helpful I would appreciate an upvote. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, congrats on reaching the 100! (And it's a well-deserved upvote, since it's an interesting question. Although it might be migrated to retrocomputing.se in the next years...)

Comment: yeah, that could very well be the case, and thanks ;)

Comment: That still seems like a bug. If it's going to do that, it should automatically scroll up so that the found text is not hidden under the find dialog. Though I'm not sure why it wasn't implemented like every other version of that same dialog, where it will move out of the way.

Answer (score 3):

This new Find window seems to have been introduced with the latest
Windows 11 update. I agree that the implementation is very badly
designed with this window being placed *always* in the middle of
the notepad window.

For the moment, I think that all you can do is write a bug-report
using the Feedback Hub, and wait for Microsoft to do something
about it.

In the meantime, the only workaround I was able to find is to widen
the notepad window enough for the Find to move to the right of the text.

You could also move to a third-party product, for example the free
and excellent [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
See also
[How to replace Notepad with Notepad++ in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-replace-notepad-with-notepad-in-windows-10).

Comment: so annoying, right?  also, moving between tabs and notepad just decides to re-position itself to somewhere in the top half of the document (not where I left my cursor); SO, went into notepad settings (cog icon upper right), switched "opening files" to "open a new window"--bandaid for now, but I liked the idea of having tabs, but it's waaaay too annoying to loose my place; i.e. similar artifact to the find function if you just "x" out after it highlight the word you want, like we don't want to end up at what we were looking for?! (wft MS: get your basics covered: cursor position is a thing!)